# Error installing MySQL Ubuntu 12.04, dependency?

Tags: 12.04, installation, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL server stopped working after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131722/mysql-server-stopped-working-after-upgrade)

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem (with solution) [here](http://e-mats.org/2010/01/dpkg-configure-error-for-mysql-server-5-1/):

Check the mysqllogs and syslogs for errors.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not have the file mentioned in your link.

Comment: And I do not know how to check the mysqllogs and syslogs.